# How to steer all column values (count would be changing) of result table and store the value sin an output file in TOSCA

Tags: database, automation, export-to-csv, tosca

I am trying to run a query and save the result in an output file (preferably in excel) since I need to read those values in other scripts.

I tried to Export the result in CSV file in which values with leading 00 are getting removed

Looking for a solution how to save the result in an output file without removing zeros